# Highlighting an accented search term using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've been trying to bold a search term in a sentence. If the sentence is `Engliš is spoken wörldwide.` If my search term is `spoken world` I want to get `Engliš is <b>spoken wörld</b>wide.`

I've used this function:

```
function highlightWords($text, $searchTerm){
   $corr = ['a' => '[aäâ]', 'o' => '[oöòóôõ]', 'c' => '[cç]', 's' => '[şśšșŝ]', 'y' => '[ýÿŷȳy]', 'o' => '[ôöòóøōoõ]', 'n' => '[ñńňn]',  'u' => '[üu]'];
   $key = preg_quote($searchTerm);
   $pattern = '/' . strtr($key, $corr) . '/iu';
   $text = preg_replace($pattern, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
   return $text;
}
```

It supposed to work, but I get really strange behavior. Few examples are:

Text is `Sygmaý çykdy deşdi-sähra düzünden` (sorry for the weird sentence). When `$searchTerm` is `duz` it perfectly works, I get `Sygmaý çykdy deşdi-sähra <b>düz</b>ünden`. If I change search term to `sahra`, the function returns just plain `Sygmaý çykdy deşdi-sähra düzünden`.

Works with `cykdy` and `çykdy`.

But doesn't work with neither `sygmay` nor `sygmaý`. But works with `Sygmaý` with capital letter.

What should I need to fix in order to get highlighted search term in all scenarios?

Comment: FYI: The problem that you're trying to solve with `'a' => '[aäâ]'`and the like most likely has already been solved within the [Intl extension](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.intl.php) and even if not then _but_ with Unicode of what you're already making use of (`/iu` PCRE modifiers). This as a pointer only, as you're concerned about regex specifically and IIRC it is not available in there. However for the regex case, take care you're normalizing Unicode characters for both the input and the pattern, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/8766675/367456 and related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in the function, specifically in the `$corr` array.

First, there are two "o" sections, and they are different. Those need to be combined. Second, the unaccented letter must be in the array for each letter. s does not have this, the missing "s" is what is causing this particular failure.

Fixed function:

```php
function highlightWords($text, $searchTerm)
{
    $corr    = [
        'a' => '[aäâ]', 
        'o' => '[oöòóôõøō]', 
        'c' => '[cç]', 
        's' => '[sşśšșŝ]', 
        'y' => '[yýÿŷȳ]', 
        'n' => '[nñńň]', 
        'u' => '[uü]'
    ];
    $key     = preg_quote($searchTerm);
    $pattern = '/' . strtr($key, $corr) . '/iu';
    $text    = preg_replace($pattern, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
    return $text;
}

$input = 'Sygmaý çykdy deşdi-sähra düzünden';
$term  = 'sahra';

$expected = 'Sygmaý çykdy deşdi-<b>sähra</b> düzünden';

$highlighted = highlightWords($input, $term);

assert($highlighted == $expected, 'Term should be marked bold');
echo $highlighted . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Good catches, my eyes were going blurry looking at the accents and I missed some tails and whatnot.

Comment: Good answer : ) well seen.